# mdframed and footnote

Tags: mdframed

I use an mdframed-based example environment that uses greek characters for denoting footnote inside this environment. The problem is that when I start using xelatex (UTF-8 encoding) with the Minion Pro fonts, the footnote markers are not printed as superscripts as usual, but as normal letters. See the attached MWE. Is it possible to fix this situation? Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[nonumeralsign]{xgreek}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\setlanguage{monogreek}}{}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\setlanguage{american}}{}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usetwoside]{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newcommand{\mple}[1]{\blue{#1}\blackink}
\def\blackink{\special{color cmyk 0 0 0 1.}}
\def\whiteink{\special{color cmyk 0 0 0 0}}

\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\def\theexample{\mple{\thechapter-\arabic{example}}\blackink}
\newenvironment{example}[2][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip\noindent
\mdfsetup{frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
frametitlealignment=\raggedright }
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=blue!8]
\cyan\hrulefill\blackink \\
\colorbox{cyan}{\textbf {\whiteink{\large{Example~\theexample}\rule[-6pt]{0ex}{4ex} }\blackink     #1}} \smallskip $\quad$ \textbf {\mple{#2}} \\[-3.5pt]
\cyan\hrulefill\blackink}{${}$\\\cyan\hrulefill\blackink\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{Sample example.}

This is just an example\footnote{This is a footnote.} to show the problem.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: GIven that Minion Pro is a commercial font (as far as I know), we probably do not have access to it. Could you provide an image of what you see?

Comment: BTW: note that the `titletoc` is probably not compatible with `memoir`

Comment: I provided an image with the output i get, Thanks for your answer. I think that Minion Pro is free since it can be freely download from internet, e.g from https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/minion-pro.

Comment: It seems a bit sus to me that a person can legally just upload a font owned by adobe

Comment: I do not know what happens, this version is declared as free, maybe this is the one i found. Check this link https://www.wfonts.com/font/minion-pro. I dont know if this is legal or not.

Comment: I would still be very careful, I haven't seen any of the sites mention licensing yet, so questionable...

Comment: I have tested your MWE with a different font (DejaVu Serif) and there the problem does not occur, so maybe (your version of) Minion Pro is the issue. Could you try the simplified MWE `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[nonumeralsign]{xgreek}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Minipage\footnote{footnote}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}` to see if this also reproduces the issue for you?

Comment: This mwe does not reproduce the error and as far as I know, the footnotes in mdframed are impelented in the same way as minipage. Therefore i have to use another font?

Comment: Try if it works if you remove `\usepackage{xltxtra}` and use only `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead.

Comment: Yes it worked! thanks a lot! (I hope this substitution is safe for the rest of the document :-)) At least, the compilation stage is performed correctly.